# Replace .so file in android apk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

is it possible to replace .so file in android app without source code?
I am creating app which use some .so files under LGPL license v2.1 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html
License says: *"...you must provide complete object files to the recipients, so that they can relink them with the library after making changes to the library and recompiling it..."*

Is it possible to replace .so file and recompile app without source code e.g. in existing apk? I can't give user source codes. Or some option to give user .class files so he can create apk?
Is it even possible and if so, what are options?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace a .so file in an apk. Just use 7zip to open the apk replace the file and you are done.

About gpl: you should have 2 libraries, one so for your code and one for the code you borrowed, this way the user can replace the so for the library, but your code cannot be changed. You can also put a check for the libs version and just exit if it was changed.

Comment: Thanks for response. It looks simple.
I don't get part about gpl. Why should I have 2 libraries? I have only one .so file in libs/armeabi and according to LGPL I must give option to user to replace this .so with his changed version. So user can create his .so file, open apk, replace .so file. If user will change .so and app will not work correctly because of changes in .so it's not big deal. I just must give him this option.

Comment: FWIW, replacing files with a Zip utility will only work for an un-signed APK.  For a signed APK, downloaded from the Play Store, you'd have to re-sign it after updating the .so.

Comment: Because any code that is statically linked against LGPL code must have it's source code available.  IE: All the other code in that single .so.  (See section 7a, which then triggers section 4.)